# Dynamic Switch Case in Prolog

Tags: prolog, switch-statement

How can I implement **switch case** using **Prolog** Programming Language? I'm very new to the language that is why I have not tried by myself!
Let's say we want to change this Java Switch Case into Prolog:

```
    int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what type of "switch case" you're after? In what  sense is it dynamic? Generally I would say you cannot do that in prolog, but you can probably model the program logic in another way such that it works.

Comment: The dynamic switch case, strictly speaking, implements a separate function for each different switch action you wish to take. What makes it compact is that it uses the function indexing feature of dynamic link libraries and the case is executed by converting the case value directly to a function index in the DLL. Prolog have a feature for building predicates indexable in a DLL. But the question makes me think you're trying to apply imperative language logic to a relational language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch statements in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764778/switch-statements-in-prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use imperative programming in Prolog. However, the imperative code:

```
switch(N) {
    case 1: procedure1(); break;
    case 2: procedure2(); break;
    default: procedure(); break;
    }
```

May be written as:

```
switch(1) :-
  procedure1.
switch(2) :-
  procedure2.
switch(_) :-
  procedure;
```